# IOS application crashes on splash screen after about 5 days

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I've created an application for iOS using React Native, but a couple of days after installing the app via Xcode on an actual iPhone, it just quits the app .3 seconds after I launch the application. It works fine the first couple of days if I uninstall and install again, but then the problem reappears after 4-5 days. I have no clue if this is something related to RN or if I'm just a complete noob skipping a lot of important Xcode-related stuff. Before installing, I change the scheme from debug to release, is there something I'm missing? Can't seem to find anyone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

For the App to keep working, you need to install it in one of the following ways:

- ad-hock (e.g. crashlytics)
- App store
- In-house (need Enterprise license)

App installed via XCode and no certificates will "expire" after 1 week or so.